# Universal settings for Eclipse autoformatter?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

My team and I have some inconsistencies in the way Eclipse auto-formats our code.

Because of this, I'd like to make a universal autoformat settings file that I can push into our repo for everybody to use. The only problem is I cannot seem to find such a file, even if it does exist. I know Eclipse stores settings largely in XML files in the `.metedata` directory of the workbench, but I cannot find anything there relating to formatting. Any help is appreciated in locating this file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse stores the selected formatter in the project settings directory (`.settings` directory within a project). Within this directory you will find the project specific formatter rules for Java files in the files `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` and `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs`.

Checking out a project from version control system that includes this file Eclipse automatically uses the defined formatting rules. Only the name of the formatter profile will change as it the profile name is not known in the Eclipse workspace. But besides that the formatter works without problems.

Therefore you should use your Eclipse to define a formatter profile, then apply it to all your projects and commit all the files `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` and `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` files to your version control system.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure if this exists somewhere in the `.metadata` directory but I was able to find an easy way to create this file if you cannot find it like me. Simply go to Eclipse Settings -> Format(for whatever language you care about). There you will see a few default profiles that are supplied with the software. You can export these as `XML` wherever you like, and then tweak them as needed and reload them into Eclipse settings when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, you would create it by opening the project's Properties dialog and looking for a property page for the formatter. It should present an option to override the workspace preferences inside the project, in which case it should save that information into the project automatically and then load it automatically when your team picks up the changes.